# Why is my endpoint returning "401 not authorized" when i'm configuring everything correctly to authenticate the user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem that when the user makes login and send his JWT token in the response when he try to access authorized endpoint it returns 401 always i don't know why he's not authenticated even if he has JWT?

Here is the program.cs code:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using ProuductsShopWepAPI.Models;
using ProuductsShopWepAPI.Reopositories;
using ProuductsShopWepAPI.RepositoriesContracts;
using ProuductsShopWepAPI.Services;
using ProuductsShopWepAPI.ServicesContracts;
using System.Text;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{

    options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Description = "Please enter a valid token",
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.Http,
        BearerFormat = "JWT",
        Scheme = "Bearer"
    });
    options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement
    {
        {
            new OpenApiSecurityScheme
            {
                Reference = new OpenApiReference
                {
                    Type=ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                    Id="Bearer"
                }
            },
            Array.Empty<string>()
        }
    });
});


// Add Api services
builder.Services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICategoryRepository, CategoryRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAccountService, AccountService>();

// Configure Entity frame work
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"));
});

// Configure jwt authentication
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
        {
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["JWT:Issuer"],
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["JWT:Audience"],
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["JWT:Key"])),
        };
    });

//Configure Identity
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 5;
    options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();


//Configure CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(policy =>
    {
        policy.AllowAnyHeader();
        policy.AllowAnyMethod();
        policy.AllowAnyOrigin();

    });
});


builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Events.OnRedirectToAccessDenied =
        options.Events.OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized;
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        };
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors();
app.UseResponseCaching();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

and this is the code that generates the JWT token:

```cs
public async Task<JwtSecurityToken> CreateJwtAsync(LoginDTO loginDTO)
{
    var user = new IdentityUser()
    {
        Email = loginDTO.Email
    };
    var issuer = _configuration["JWT:Issuer"];
    var audience = _configuration["JWT:Audience"];
    var key = _configuration["JWT:key"];

    var signingCredintials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key)), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user) ?? new List<Claim>();

    foreach (var role in roles)
    {
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
    }
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, loginDTO.Email));

    var jwtObject = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: issuer,
        audience: audience,
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(1000),
        signingCredentials: signingCredintials
        );

    return jwtObject;

}
```

Login endpoint:

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginDTO loginDTO)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var details = new ValidationProblemDetails(ModelState);
                details.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
                return BadRequest(details);
            }
            var isLoginValid = await _accountService.IsLoginValidAsync(loginDTO);

            if (!isLoginValid) throw new Exception("Email or password is not valid");

            var jwtObject = await _accountService.CreateJwtAsync(loginDTO);

            var stringJwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwtObject);
            HttpContext.Response.Headers["Authorization"] = stringJwt;
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, stringJwt);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails();
            problemDetails.Detail = ex.Message;
            problemDetails.Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, problemDetails);
        }

    }
```

Here is Seed/Categories endpoint

```cs
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Categories()
    {
        var newCategoriees = new List<Category>();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader($"{_environment.ContentRootPath}/Data/amazon_categories.csv"))
        {
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var dic = _categoryRepository.GetAll();
                var dic1 = await dic.ToDictionaryAsync(c => c.Id);
                var categories = csv.GetRecordsAsync<ProductCategorie>();
                await foreach (var category in categories)
                {
                    if (!dic1.ContainsKey(long.Parse(category.id)))
                    {
                        var newCategory = new Category();
                        newCategory.Id = long.Parse(category.id);
                        newCategory.Name = category.category_name;
                        newCategoriees.Add(newCategory);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        await _categoryRepository.AddCategoriesAsync(newCategoriees);
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status200OK, $"{newCategoriees.Count} categories has been added");

    }
```

as you see here even though the user has authorization in the request header it returns 401 status code error instead making him seed the categories in the database
[image]
if you know how to solve this problem then please tell me.

Comment: What does your Categories endpoint look like?

Comment: I edited the question and put seed/categories endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your categories endpoint, replace `[Authorize]` with:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: Thank you it works now but why it behave like this ?

Comment: Because the endpoint needs to know that you're dealing with JWT. .NET will then run it's JWT authentication middleware - essentially reading the JWT token and allowing / denying access. You can also add the Authorize attribute to the whole controller - then you don't need to specify it on each endpoint. Please mark this post as the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Authorize attribute for you controller or action for example (may you have incorrect AuthenticationSchemes for /[controller]/[action] )

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Comment: Thank you it works now but why it behave like this ?

Comment: AddIdentityCore() and AddIdentity() different,  look at this

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityServiceCollectionExtensions.cs#L38-L102

Comment: @A_AhMaD AddIdentity  build on cookie base